# Hakell surplus binding in pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have the following snippet out of an Interpreter:

```
type Ident = String
type Value = Int
type State = Ident -> Value

iniState :: State

iniState = \ident -> error "internal error initial state"


updateS :: State -> (Ident, Value) -> State

updateS s (ident, val) ident' | ident' == ident = val
                              | otherwise = s ident'
```

where does the ident' in the pattern of updateS come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument is from the `Ident` argument to the function in the type `State`.

Using `type` defines a synonym for another type (quite literally a synonym). In other words, the following type signatures are all the same:

```
State -> (Ident, Value) -> State 
(Ident -> Value) -> (Ident, Value) -> (Ident -> Value)
(Ident -> Value) -> (Ident, Value) -> Ident -> Value
```

(You could also replace `Ident` with `String` and `Value` with `Int` to do a full expansion.)

The last one makes it clear that `updateS` could take 3 parameters: a function `Ident -> Value`, a pair `(Ident, Value)` and a single `Ident`.

Answer (score 3):

`updateS` is a function that takes three parameters.  If you replace `State` with its definition in the type signature, you get

```
updateS :: (Ident -> Value) -> (Ident, Value) -> Ident -> Value
```

So `ident'` is the third parameter of the function, which has type `Ident`.

Looking at the bigger picture, `updateS` turns a `State` and an `(Ident, Value)` pair into a new `State`.  We can reason about what kind of `State` is returned.  If we evaluate `updateS s (ident, val)`, we get a `State` that acts like `s` in most situations, except that if it's is called with an argument equal to `ident`, it returns `val`.